# sed + how to minimize sed pipe line and do the sed in one shoot

Tags: linux, sed, pipe

Is it possible to do the following with one sed command without another two sed pipe line ?

```
sed s"/obbama/trump/" | sed s'/"//g' | sed s'/://g'
```

The sed as described here needs to replace the word obbama with trump and remove the characters ' " ' and ':'

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the [POSIX sed man page](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/utilities/sed.html)

> The script shall be obtained from either the script operand string or
>   a combination of the option-arguments from the *-e script* and *-f
>   script-file* options.

The first one ("the script operand string") is essentially handled by the other answer here (semi-colon separation).

With `-e`:

```
$ sed -e "s/obbama/trump/" -e 's/"//g' -e 's/://g'
```

With `-f`:

```
$ cat sed-script
s/obbama/trump/
s/"//g
s/://g
$ sed -f sed-script
```

BTW, it's more conventional to put the "s" inside the quotes in each of your substitution directives which I've done with the `-e` example.

Answer (score 3):

`sed` is a scripting language that, like sh or awk or perl or any other, allows multiple statements within the script.  You separate each sed statement with a semi-colon `;`, or with a new line.  e.g.

```
sed 's/obbama/trump/; s/"//g; s/://g'
```

or

```
sed 's/obbama/trump/
s/"//g
s/://g'
```

The space character after the `;` is optional but IMO makes the sed script more readable.

Comment: @yael: That is also possible with a regex: `sed 's/obbama/trump/;s/[":]//g'`

Comment: yeah, i'd merge the last two into one too - but the point here was to show how to have multiple statements in one script, not to optimise some trivial regular expressions.